# How would I set multiple numerical values to a single character/categorical using mapvalues in R?

Tags: r

So I normally use mapvalues to set a single numerical value to text, then convert it later to a factor, e.g.

```
  mydata$data<- mapvalues(mydata$columnheader, from = c("1", "0", "-1", "-3"), to = c("Yes", "No", "Dont know", "Prefer not to say"))
  mydata$data<- as.factor(mydata$data)
```

However, I have come to a point where I want several values mapped onto a single value, ie I would want 1, 100 and 1000 to be mapped to "yes", 0, 000 and 0000 to "no" etc, rather than just a single value mapped to a single character string. Is there an easy way to do this within mapvalues that doesnt involve using several nested if statements?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: `mapvalues(x, c(1, 100, 1000, 0, 000, 0000), rep(c("yes", "no"), each=3))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `recode` from the `car` package, or just `ifelse`.

```
# Define vector
vals <- c("1","100","1000","0","000","0000")

library(car)
recode(vals, 'c("1","100","1000") = "yes"; c("0","000","0000") = "no"')
#[1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"  "no"  "no" 

ifelse(vals %in% c("1","100","1000"), "yes",
       ifelse(vals %in% c("0","000","0000"), "no", NA))
#[1] "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"  "no"  "no"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help